# How to execute a bash script from a Python string in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook and would like to execute a bash script from a python string. I have a python cell creating the bash script which then I need to print, copy to another cell, and then run it. Is it possible to use something like `exec('print('hello world!')')`?

Here is an example of my bash script:

```
%%bash -s "$folder_dir" "$name_0" "$name_1" "$name_2" "$name_3" "$name_4" "$name_5" "$name_6" "$name_7" "$name_8" "$name_9" "$name_10" "$name_11"

cd $1

ds9 ${2} ${3} ${4} ${5} ${6} ${7} ${8} ${9} ${10} ${11} ${12} ${13}
```

If not possible, then how can I go to a different directory, and run

```
ds9 dir1 dir2 dir3 ...
```

within my Jupyter Notebook since I only can initialize dir's using python. Note that the number of dir's is not fixed every time I run my code. `ds9` is just a command to open multiple astronomical images at the same time.

I know I can save my bash script to a .sh file and execute that, but I am looking for a classier solution.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something in [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html)?

Comment: `${2}` gives you absolutely no advantage in correctness over `$2`, unless you're performing string concatenation, whereas `"$2"` would actually ensure that your second argument is passed as a single string, rather than being potentially split or globbed into multiple arguments or passed as no arguments at all (if it contains no characters that aren't in IFS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is the Right Thing for invoking external software -- in a shell or otherwise -- from Python.

```
import subprocess

folder_dir="/" # your directory
names=["name_one", "name_two"]   # this is your list of names you want to open

subprocess.check_call(
    ['cd "$1" || exit; shift; exec ds9 "$@"', "_", folder_dir] + names,
    shell=True)
```

---

#### How it works (Python)

When passing a Python list with `shell=True`, the first item in that list is the script to run; the second is the value of `$0` when that script is running, and subsequent items are values for `$1` and onward.

Note that this runs `sh -c '...'` with your command. `sh` is not bash, but (in modern systems) a POSIX sh interpreter. It's thus important not to use bash-only syntax in this context.

#### How it works (Shell)

Let's go over this line-by-line:

```
cd "$1" || exit # try to cd to the directory passed as $1; abort if that fails
shift           # remove $1 from our argument list; the old $2 is now $1, &c.
exec ds9 "$@"   # replace the shell in memory with the "ds9" program (as an efficiency
                # ...measure), with our argument list appended to it.
```

Note that `"$1"` and `"$@"` are quoted. Any unquoted expansion will be string-split and glob-expanded; without this change, you won't be able to open files with spaces in their names.

Comment: Hah! It worked! Thanks a lot! My code is now 75% shorter.
I knew about this package, but I didn't know you could use it like this.